# RS232 connection

Tags: serial

The picture in this post is from a Casio XJ-A140 projector.  Casio decided to use a proprietary connector for serial communication that is no longer available.  I am trying to get this projector to communicate with a pc.  Casio would not give me the pinout to DE-9.  I attached wires to the test points in the image (232Rx,232Tx,exc2,UD-,UD+,TxD-D and VUSB) and routed the wires out of the projector.  I tried connecting 232Tx to pin 3, 232Rx to pin 2 and gnd to gnd of the serial connection on my pc but I still get no response when sending an ASCII command to the projector.  Does anyone have any ideas on what else I can try?

[Casio YK-5 Serial Cable](https://support.casio.com/en/manual/007/YK-5_RS-232C_Control_E_EN.pdf)

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: That connector sort of looks round. Are you sure it's not a DIN-9 connector?

Comment: you provided incomplete information... please add a picture of the connector

Comment: Finally got it working with the help of a logic analyzer.  The ASCII string needs to include parens,  so sending (PWR1) turns the projector on with the correct connection as 232RX on the projector to Pin 2 of the DB9, 232TX on the projector to Pin 3 of the DB9 and Projector ground to Pin 5 of the DB9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could have RX and TX backwards. Even if you did what seems right in terms of DCE/DTE, they could have labeled it backwards on the board — it's not that uncommon.
- They could be using TTL or inverted TTL voltage levels instead or RS-232 ones (probably not, given the diagram, but maybe).
- They could be using any of the other 5 pins on that connector as a sense pin to detect which sort of cable is attached, and the YK-5 cable has that pin shorted to ground, pulled to ground through a resistor, or connected to DTR on the host. With that pin left floating, the projector could be in USB mode, or not accept any comms at all.

Comment: For sure, looking at MAX202 pinout, TX is output. For sure, the MAX202 is not using TTL levels on connector.

Answer (score 0):

I see here different scenarios:

1. The projector expects a string from the external host
2. The projector, before initiating any kind of communication, wants the DTR signal of the RS232 interface asserted. That is -9 Volt

Do you have a scope?

Comment: I have a terrible DSO138 scope, so not really.

Comment: I did measure voltages of the pins 
TxD-D is +10v
232Tx is -10v
ExC2 is +3v

Answer (score 0):

You never said which DE-9 gender connector you connected to. TXD is output from projector and needs to be connected to RXD of PC. Please double check the wiring. On PC side the TXD outptut is on pin 3 so if you connected projector TXD output to PC TXD output then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried connecting 232Tx to pin 3, 232Rx to pin 2 and gnd to gnd of
> the serial connection on my pc but I still get no response when
> sending an ASCII command to the projector. Does anyone have any ideas
> on what else I can try?

There are a few things. Hook it up to an oscilloscope, [check the baud rate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328748/can-we-calculate-the-baud-rate-of-rs232-communication-from-the-tx-output-signal) and the voltage levels (usually 1.8V 2.5V 3.3V and 5V.) get a usb to ttl serial converter (a good one with a real FTDI serial chip).